# Visual Studio Apache Cordova - iOS build missing Javascript files on run

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-2015, xcode7, visual-studio-cordova

Currently when building our ios app when running it is failing to load some of our JavaScript files, it is the exact same files every time.

We have renamed the files, added the file contents into different javascript files, just added some of the scripts all which have failed and the changes do not take effect.

All of our JavaScript is installed within the scripts folder within www/

We have rebuilt the project under all available Cordova CLI current using 6.3.0 now.

3 weeks to try and get a working build onto an iPhone, which have managed many times previously.

Build PC - Windows 10 using visual Studio 2015 Update 3.

Local Network MacBook Pro running remotebuild and Xcode 7.

There are no build errors no runtime errors no indication of a fault what so ever, we build to a local device on the windows PC and it starts up in Debug mode I can see the files missing in the visual Studio display.

I would appreciate if anybody can shed some light on this, I can happily display any information which might be relevant to help get a little further with this problem.

My thanks in advance for anybody who takes the time to read and or comment to this problem.

**Update**
My Colleague has taken the project into PhoneGap and built in the cloud using their services and it is exactly the same problem, two of our JavaScript files do not get loaded at runtime, causing the app to fall over. This same app builds perfectly and runs fine on android.

Comment: Have you tried clear the cordova cache and remove the platform and add the platform and build again?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT Cleared the cache, wiped the machine, reinstalled everything, built on 3 different machines the files are there on the Mac to be seen in build and all other folders but when running in Visual Studio you can see clearly that the files have not been loaded. Platform Added and removed.

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo that can reproduce this problem?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT I am going to pull it together now, been working on something just need to do a bit of code to make it work with out being connected to Bluetooth.

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT Silly question but how can I share the dropbox link with you ? I obviously do not wish to share it with the world :)

Comment: You can send it to my Email: xiaxucheng@gmail.com.

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT Elvis thank you very much for the offer, we did pull a full build together to send you but whilst waiting we carried on and found a javascript error of using => rather than >= which cause xcode to just drop the javascript files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a colleague of James, upon extensive testing and pulling the javascript files apart line by line we found the problem.

An if statement had a => rather than >= which did not show up in debug or runtime errors at all and on ios it just caused Xcode to not include the files into the build.

So anyone else missing files on run time with no errors check your code exhaustively.